# Can drag and drop capability be implemented in ARKit?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

After the release of Apple ARKit, there will be a lot of augmented reality apps will be released and I'm very new to this concept and wanna ask some questions about it.

1-) Can you implement drag and drop for ARScene? What I mean is lets say I have camera feed(ARScene) on the background and have another view on top of that having some images. Can I drag any image from that overlay and place it in my ARScene anywhere I want?

2-) If ARKit doesn't have this capability are there any other frameworks that can support this?

Thanks all.

Comment: 1-) Yes it is possible!
2-) I am not aware of any - but you can go and implement one of your own - it is not that hard to handle.

Comment: Have you done this by any chance?